# linking hyperlink of ascx to aspx

Tags: asp.net

i have a hyperlink in ascx file and its navigateurl is set in another aspx page how to link them

in aspx:

```
 HyperLink ShowRelated = (HyperLink)logout1.FindControl("hypRelated");
        ShowRelated.Visible = true;


        ShowRelated.NavigateUrl = string.Format("RelatedFields.aspx?mid={0}&fid={1}&srchid={2}&searchStr={3}&pkId={4}",
                                    MetaId, filterId, searchId, searchStr, pkId);
```

in ascx:

```
   <asp:HyperLink ID="hypRelated" data-role="button" style="text-align:center;margin:0 15px 0 15px" data-mini="true" runat="server" Visible="false">
```

Comment: And what is the problem? Please add that to your question.

Comment: You need to be more specific on what is your question!

Answer (score 0):

Simply make a property on you user control the maps to the Hyperlink and set that in your aspx page. e.g.

```
public HtperLink Related 
{
     get
     {
          return hypRelated;
     }
}
```

Then in your aspx

Just do

```
MyUserControl.Related.NavigateUrl = string.Format("RelatedFields.aspx?mid={0}&fid={1}&srchid={2}&searchStr={3}&pkId={4}",
                                    MetaId, filterId, searchId, searchStr, pkId);
```